# Use z3 to Prove Identity of Boolean/Arithmetic Formula

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm trying to use z3 to prove the following identity:

> x+y == x^y + 2*(x&y)

That is, we can replace any addition with a mixture of boolean and arithmetic instructions (example taken from Chapter 2.2, [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/basics2.pdf)).

I'm using the following z3 python snippet:

```
from z3 import *

x = BitVec("x", 32)
y = BitVec("y", 32)

lhs = x ^ y + (2*(x&y))
rhs = x + y
s = Solver()
s.add(lhs != rhs)
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

However, z3 gives me this:

> sat
>
> [y = 1509949440, x = 1040187384]

So I suppose I'm somehow using the API incorrectly. Any idea what my error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is an issue with the precedence of the `^` operator. Using

```
lhs = (x ^ y) + (2*(x&y))
```

makes the example work for me.

Comment: If I change the expression in the "rhs" variable in my code to "x-y", z3 still prints out "SAT", even though that formula is not equivalent to "x-y". Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code somewhere just to make sure I know exactly what you are trying to do? Note that when z3 finds a solution to  `lhs != rhs` it means it has found a counterexample to the proposition `lhs == rhs`.

Comment: The code above is the complete code. The only thing I changed is the expressions for "rhs".
before: `rhs = x + y`, after the change: `rhs = x - y`
The output is SAT after the change (which cannot be true, right?)

Comment: SAT means that `lhs == rhs` is not true in general because z3 has found a counterexample which it should print out. For example, `(x-y) != (x^y) + (2*(x&y))` is satisfied by x=1, y=1, and this means that `x-y == (x^y) + 2*(x&y)` is not true in general.